# OPC UA - Change Endpoint Configuration or Server Capabilities

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I've got an OPC UA server which is not capable of showing me or or less than `32652` characters through UaExpert as a string type. So my published objects strings are cut to this length.
I was wondering if i can anyhow manipulate this configuration. So i tried the following stuff:

```
private static void SetServerConfiguration(ApplicationInstance appInstance, OpcUaStartupParameters parameters)
{
    SecuredApplication securedApplication = OpcUaServerConfiguration.ConfigureOpcUaApplicationWithDefaultValues(parameters);
    appInstance.DefaultEndpointConfiguration = GenerateEndpointConfiguration(parameters);
    SetApplicationSettings(securedApplication, appInstance);
}

private static UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.EndpointConfiguration GenerateEndpointConfiguration(OpcUaStartupParameters parameters)
{
    var endpointConfiguration = new UnifiedAutomation.UaBase.EndpointConfiguration();
    endpointConfiguration.MaxStringLength = 20;
    return endpointConfiguration;
}
```

Server Capabilities in the UaExpert->Root->Objects->Server Path says the max length is `16777216`. UaExpert himself is confgured with `Stack.Serializer_MaxStringLength = 100000`

EDIT:

I'm measuring the string length by copy-paste the string into sublime Text and then counting the chars. I just realized that copy pasting the input string for the server out of a Debug session of Visual Studio shortens the string too.
Has copy-past some sort of cut-mechanism?